# SharePoint 2010 - Identify WFE - Page is been server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to identify through which Web FrontEnd a site is been shared to end user.

NOTE: I have already read some concepts in the same site, however i am specifically looking for an option in INternet Explorer throught 'View Source'.

1) Open Internet Explorer
2) Open the Sharepoint Site
3) Right Click and then select 'View Source'
4) In the view Source where can see the WEB FRONTEND name ?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box there is no way to identify the WFE in the HTML.

There are some good options in the answers to question [How to determine which WFE you are hitting?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/how-to-determine-which-wfe-you-are-hitting)